# `Error: no such device...` after installing Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, grub2

I've seen many threads about this error but I couldn't find a solution. I've installed Arch Linux alongside Windows 8. (Dual Boot).

I followed [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMgGUBDxCjo) exactly but am getting the error below at [20:35](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BMgGUBDxCjo). After a reboot I'm getting:

```
error: no such device: ad4103fa-...
Loading Linux core repo kernel...
error: file `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` not found
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

Any helps would be great.

Comment: If you want to install Arch, use the official documentation or the Beginners' Guide, not some random video that is likely both outdated and incorrect...

Comment: That video is about year 2013

Comment: That doesn't mean that some guy with a hip hop soundtrack and an inability to complete a sentence installing Arch in a Virtual Machine will be of any help to you. **Read** the documentation provided by the community; if you aren't prepared to do that for the install, there is no reason to believe you will enjoy/understand Arch.

Comment: @jasonwryan Thank you. The problem was solved.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the answer.

Put Arch DVD or Flash Drive and boot it again.

Retry following commands :

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt #sda1 is `boot` partition
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/home #sda3 is `home` partition
arch-chroot /mnt
pacman -S os-prober
grub-install /dev/sda
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
exit
reboot
```

Cheers...

Comment: When I ran lsblk, I noticed that my partition was not mounted some reason.... following this fixed it! Thanks!